# Converting fillable word document to fillable pdf file using java

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, aspose.words, fillable

I want to convert my fillable word document into fillable pdf document? Is there any solution?

I used aspose.words to insert some fill in forms into document and then converted it into PDF, but from fill-in forms were just empty fields with border...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [PdfSaveOptions.PreserveFormFields](https://reference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/pdfsaveoptions/#setPreserveFormFields-boolean) options to preserve form fields in PDF:

```cs
Document doc = new Document("C:\\Temp\\in.docx");
PdfSaveOptions opt = new PdfSaveOptions();
opt.setPreserveFormFields(true);
doc.save("C:\\Temp\\out.pdf", opt);
```